# I m getting "Expected even number of keys and values, got 1." while running post request in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

my code is as shown below, which also makes use of JSONLibrary.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    RequestsLibrary     
Library    JSONLibrary    
Library    Collections 

*** Variables ***
${Base_URL}   http://example.com



*** Keywords ***
      ${json_string}=    catenate
    \     ...    {
   \    ...                 "name":"abc",
  \    ...                    "sourceConn":{"storType":"abc","connConfig":[
   \    ...                                {"key":"endpoint","value":"abc.com"},
  \    ...                           {"key":"bucketname","value":"c2c-migration"},
  \    ...                       {"key":"region","value":"us-east-1"},
  \    ...                       {"key":"access","value":"abcdgggggfgffg"},
  \    ...                           {"key":"security","value":"sdfggffggfgghghghggf"}
   \    ...                       ]},



  \    ...                    "destConn":{"storType":"abg","connConfig":[
  \    ...                               {"key":"endpoint","value":"s3.us-east.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud"},
   \    ...                              {"key":"bucketname","value":"addddf"},
    \    ...                             {"key":"region","value":"us-east"},
  \    ...                               {"key":"access","value":"gffdfgfggbvgvvv"},
   \    ...                              {"key":"security","value":"ghtyrtrdrfdfdf"}
   \    ...                         ]},
   \    ...                   "type":"migration",
   \    ...                   "remainSource": true,
  \    ...                "Filter": {
   \    ...                   "ObjectList": ["New Text Document (2).txt" ,"demo.txt","Blog.mp4","Captur_e.JPG"]
  \    ...                  }
  \    ...                }


*** Test Cases ***
post_001
    Create Session    post_01   ${Base_URL}
    ${body}=   Create Dictionary   ${ Json_String} 

     ${header}=  Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/json     
     ${Response}=   Post Request    post_01    /v1/adminTenantId/plans  data=${body}  headers=${header}
    Log To Console    ${Response.status_code}
    Log To Console    ${Response.content}
```

Comment: what library are making use of? what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: This library I m using<br> *** Settings ***<br>
<br>Library    RequestsLibrary     <br>
<br>Library    JSONLibrary    <br>
<br>Library    Collections <br>

Comment: and in ${Json}  i have use json formate data

Comment: paste complete code, what is AddData? is it a custom keyword? explain all the details in the question, otherwise, the question would become difficult to answer.

Comment: which keyword is erroring out with the error described in the question?

Comment: please fix the formatting of your code. There's a bunch of odd html mixed in with the code, making it hard to read the code, and making it impossible to copy and paste the code.

Comment: AddData is custom keywork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem all you need to do is to correct the way in which you are creating dictionary. See the working code below, **i have only corrected your code and have not modified your code completely**.

**ISSUE IS HERE** - you need to provide both key and value i.e key=value while creating a dictionary, you have provided only value and not key, hence, the error is "expected an even number..."

```
before 
 ${body}=   Create Dictionary   ${json_String}

after
 ${body}=   Create Dictionary   js=${json_String}
```

**WORKING CODE**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    RequestsLibrary
Library    JSONLibrary
Library    Collections

*** Variables ***
${Base_URL}   http://example.com




*** Test Cases ***
post_001
    Create Session    post_01   ${Base_URL}
      ${json_string}=    catenate
    \     ...    {
   \    ...                 "name":"abc",
  \    ...                    "sourceConn":{"storType":"abc","connConfig":[
   \    ...                                {"key":"endpoint","value":"abc.com"},
  \    ...                           {"key":"bucketname","value":"c2c-migration"},
  \    ...                       {"key":"region","value":"us-east-1"},
  \    ...                       {"key":"access","value":"abcdgggggfgffg"},
  \    ...                           {"key":"security","value":"sdfggffggfgghghghggf"}
   \    ...                       ]},



  \    ...                    "destConn":{"storType":"abg","connConfig":[
  \    ...                               {"key":"endpoint","value":"s3.us-east.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud"},
   \    ...                              {"key":"bucketname","value":"addddf"},
    \    ...                             {"key":"region","value":"us-east"},
  \    ...                               {"key":"access","value":"gffdfgfggbvgvvv"},
   \    ...                              {"key":"security","value":"ghtyrtrdrfdfdf"}
   \    ...                         ]},
   \    ...                   "type":"migration",
   \    ...                   "remainSource": true,
  \    ...                "Filter": {
   \    ...                   "ObjectList": ["New Text Document (2).txt" ,"demo.txt","Blog.mp4","Captur_e.JPG"]
  \    ...                  }
  \    ...                }



    ${body}=   Create Dictionary   js=${json_String}



     ${header}=  Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/json
     ${Response}=   Post Request    post_01     /v1/adminTenantId/plans     data=${body}        headers=${header}
    Log To Console    ${Response.status_code}
    Log To Console    ${Response.content}
```

**Output**

```
(rf1) C:\Users\kgurupra>robot 2.robot
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
[ WARN ] Error in file 'C:\Users\kgurupra\2.robot': Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2.
==============================================================================
2
==============================================================================
post_001                                                              .....404
.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
        <head>
                <title>404 - Not Found</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="//wpc.75674.betacdn.net/0075674/www/ec_tpm_bcon.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>

post_001                                                              | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2                                                                     | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Users\kgurupra\output.xml
Log:     C:\Users\kgurupra\log.html
Report:  C:\Users\kgurupra\report.html
```

Comment: What you've done with the `Create Dictionary   js=${json_String}` is to create a dictionary with a key "js" and value that string - and it continues to be a string, though when printed looks like a dict itself. The API it is sent to most probably expects a predefined structure, which is not like this one.

Comment: @TodorMinakov ${json_string} contains a json (which is a string), the questioniere has not reverted with any more details other than what is been shown to us. Hence, i have take it as key=value i.e js=${json_string} and moved on... SInce, the person who has asked the question is only inteted to solve the ERROR as opposed to expaining about the intention behind the question. BTW, i have not done anything other than what you have already described in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Though you haven't said it, I'm guessing the error comes from this line:

```
${body}=   Create Dictionary    ${Json}
```

In the comments, you say `${Json}` is json formatted data. But this doesn't matter - the keyword creates a dictionary, and expects key-value pairs, which are going to become its members. 
It is called either with:

```
key_name=a_value
```

- e.g. using the assignment, or as separate arguments to the keyword - always an even number:

  key_name    a_value

If the `${Json}` variable's value is a dictionary - which I doubt, you could unpack it during the call:

```
${body}=   Create Dictionary    &{Json}
```

Note the ampersand in front of its name, vs the usual dollar sign.

And if its a string, then you could transform it to a dictionary through the python's `json` library. But, you'll have a name conflict (because your variable is also named "json" and shadows the standard lib); if the var is called "json1":

```
${body}=   Evaluate    json.loads($json1)    json
```

And now `${body}` is a dictionary.

Comment: In the ${ json} I have put  complex json data ....ND the error comes from ${body}

Comment: On which line/which call?

Comment: can you check now..I have edited my code ....give sample json value and sample URL

Comment: Still - which line of the case code is throwing the exception?

Comment: ${body}= Create Dictionary ${ Json_String}

Comment: Then, I stand behind my answer - the issue is you have created a json like string with that `Catenate` keyword, and you want `Create Dictionary` to migically transform it to a dictionary. It cannot. Thus, please use the `json.loads()` approach in the second part of my answer.